# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the NodeMailerService (?, AppConfigService)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I am facing this error although I have imported MailerModule in app.module and using it in other module named 'user.module'.
Attaching error Image and code

**App.Module**

```
 import { NodeMailerService } from './mailer/mailer.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MailerModule.forRootAsync({
      inject: [AppConfigService],
      useFactory: (configService: AppConfigService) => {
        const config = configService.smtpEmailObject;
        return { ...config }
      },
    })
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Users.Module**

```
import { NodeMailerService } from '../mailer/mailer.service';
@Module({
  imports: [],
  providers: [UsersService, ...userProviders, ...userMetaProviders,NodeMailerService],
  exports: [UsersService],
  controllers: [UsersController]
})
export class UsersModule { }
```

**Error Image**
[image: What is the solution.I am not able to figure out]

Answer (score 0):

Create MailerModule, add NodeMailerService to the providers and export NodeMailerService from it. Then import MailerModule in Users.Module and delete NodeMailerService from Users.Module.